({"err":{"InstructionError":[1,"PrivilegeEscalation"]}})
Got this error while buying NFT :-
pub fn buy_nft(ctx: Context<BuyNft>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Buying nft");

        let pda_account = &ctx.accounts.pda_account;
        let seller = &ctx.accounts.seller;
        let buyer = &ctx.accounts.buyer;

        token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.pda_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.pda_signer.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            1,
        )?;

        **seller.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += pda_account.price;
        **buyer.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= pda_account.price;

        Ok(())
    }
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct BuyNft<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    /// CHECK: Validate address by deriving pda
    #[account(mut)]
    pub seller: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub pda_account: Account<'info, Sale>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub pda_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    /// CHECK: Validate address by deriving pda
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"sale", mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub pda_signer: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

This is a test case :-
it('Buy NFT', async () => {
      const buyerTokenAccountAddress = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mintKeyPair.publicKey,
        buyerKeypair.publicKey
    );

    const [pdaAccount, bump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [Buffer.from('sale'), mintKeyPair.publicKey.toBuffer()],
        program.programId
    );

    const pdaTokenAccountAddress = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mintKeyPair.publicKey,
        pdaAccount,
        true
    );

    const createBuyerTokenAccountIx = createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        payer.publicKey,
        buyerTokenAccountAddress,
        buyerKeypair.publicKey,
        mintKeyPair.publicKey
    );

    try {
        const buyTransactionSignature = await program.methods
            .buyNft()
            .accounts({
                buyer: buyerKeypair.publicKey,
                buyerTokenAccount: buyerTokenAccountAddress,
                seller: payer.publicKey,
                pdaAccount,
                pdaTokenAccount: pdaTokenAccountAddress,
                mint: mintKeyPair.publicKey,
                pdaSigner: pdaAccount,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            })
            .preInstructions([createBuyerTokenAccountIx])
            .signers([buyerKeypair])
            .rpc({ skipPreflight: true });

        console.log('NFT purchased');
        console.log('Transaction signature', buyTransactionSignature);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error buying NFT:', error);
    }
    });


Since you are using pda_signer as the authority, you need to add the signer seeds for this account and use the new_with_signer() method
        let bump = &[YOUR PDA ACCOUNT BUMP HERE];
        let signer_seeds = &[&[PDA SEEDS GO HERE, bump][..]];

        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.pda_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.pda_signer.to_account_info(),
        };

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer_seeds);

        transfer_checked(cpi_ctx, amount, ctx.accounts.mint.decimals)?; 



Thank you for your response. It worked.
